# SQL stored procedure - how to optimize slow delete?

Tags: sql, database, azure

I've got a seemingly simple stored procedure that is taking too long to run (25 minutes on about 1 million records). I was wondering what I can do to speed it up. It's just deleting records in a given set of statuses.

Here's the entire procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTTWFilters]
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM TMW 
    WHERE STATUS IN ('AVAIL', 'CANCL', 'CONTACTED', 'EDI-IN', 'NOFRGHT', 'QUOTE');
END
```

I can obviously beef up my Azure SQL instance to run faster, but are there other ways to improve? Is my syntax not ideal? Do I need to index the STATUS column? Thanks!

Comment: Can you get an actual execution plan for this query? Most likely, indexing that `STATUS` column would be helpful - if you limit the number of rows matched down enough by using these status values.

Comment: Please paste the plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and post the resulting link to your question

Comment: I posted the plan.  I don't really know how to read it though.  Please advise if something stands out to you.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry - here it is: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1jHemr5d

Comment: You need to **actually run** the stored procedure and get the **actual execution plan** from that execution; not the execution plan from when you **create** the stored procedure (which is what you posted) - that doesn't help us diagnose perf problem during the execution ...

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from deleting in several batches. One thing you could try would be several deletes one for each status instead of doing all together, this would reduce the log usage per transaction, ideally with an index on `status`

Comment: Thanks.  I did what Stu suggested and it seems to run faster.

Comment: @sirocode Glad to hear that. Would you mind me post  that as the answer to end your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer, as it is generally the case with large data update operations, is to break it up into several smaller batches.

Every DML statement, by default, starts an implicit transaction, whether explicitly declared or not. By running the delete affecting a large number of rows in a single batch, locks are held on indexes and the base table for the duration of the operation and the log file will continue to grow, internally creating new VLFs for the entire transaction.

Moreover, if the delete is aborted before it completes, the rollback may well take considerably longer to complete since they are always single-threaded.

Breaking into batches, usually performed in some form of loop working progressively through a range of key values, allows the deletes to occur in smaller more manageable chunks. In this case, having a range of different status-values to delete separately appears to be enough to effect a worthwhile improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use top keyword to delete large amount of data by using loop or use = sign instead of in keyword.